# Data Entity framework performance issue ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

My scenario i want to retrieve the data from a table  but this table joined another 5 tables. I want to call only  parent table `EnrolTrainingProgram trainingprogram` but entity framework create all 5 table instance that why my query performance is so slow.

My question , only i want to query & retrieve data from parent table no need to create child Instance . How can i exclude other table instance to retrieve faster ?

```
EnrolTrainingProgram runningProgram = Find(id); 
public virtual T Find(int id)
        {

            return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
```

EnrolTrainingProgram this class with relation with other 5 classes like...

```
ForeignKey("TrainingProgram") 
ForeignKey("TrainingModule")
. 
. 
ForeignKey("User")
```

When i retrieve data following function "Find(id)" that performance too slow

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what your problem is without seeing any code, but make sure that you have Lazy Loading enabled for your context.

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx